# Sum of index to sum of elements of Array (Optimization)

Tags: java, python, algorithm, optimization

You got starting no. of element suppose N, you are provided with N numbers with a space in next line. Determine the number of cases in that array such that it follows following rule - `i+j=array[i]+array[j]` where i and j are index and `i<j`.

For ex,
**Input-**

```
5
1 0 2 4 3
```

**Output-**

```
4
```

**Explanation-**

`Elements of array at index (0,1), (1,3), (3,4) and (0,4) follows the above rule`

For now, I can solve it using O(n*n) by traversing all the element. Can you please come up with optimized code.?

My code in python is as follows:

```
n=int(input())
arr=list(map(int,input.split(' ')))
count=0
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1,n):
        if(i+j==arr[i]+arr[j]):
            count+=1
print(count)
```

My code in Java (snippet) is as follows:

```
int n=sc.nextInt(); //sc is scanner
int a[]=new int[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  a[i]=sc.nextInt();
}
int count=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{  for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
       if(i+j==a[i]+a[j])
          count++;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: What code do you already have?

Comment: as you did is the way of doing it, since the numbers dont need to follow any rule and can be arbitrary

Comment: @Mark Already mentioned my code. Please check.

Comment: @Ronny How is this related to Java?

Comment: @GhostCat Please see my effort as mentioned in the edited question and I need logic or explanation, Language does not matter. If still not cleared please check my tag. Thanks

Comment: @Mark You can give me solution in any of the languages. I just need logic to optimize it.

Comment: The code looks OK to me. What kind of optimizations are you looking for and why?

Comment: If your code runs without errors, [codereview.se] may be a better place to ask on.

Comment: @Goyo when i run it in java or python it takes too much time as per competitive compiler and again it's time complexity is high. Do we have any other approach to solve this question (like dp or algo or using any other data structure).

Comment: I think your java code is just wrong. Anyway what makes you think you can do this in time < O(n*n)?

Comment: @Goyo Please check now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First notice that the condition `i+j=array[i]+array[j]` is equivalent to:

> ```
> (array[i] - i) + (array[j] -- j) == 0
> ```

So calculate `array[i] - i` for each `i`. In your example you will get `[1, -1, 0, 1, -1]`. **Edit:** With thanks to the comment by maaartinus since only a count of pairs is asked for, we also only need a count of each calculated difference. So for each difference, store how many times it occurs as a positive difference and how many as a negative. Use a map with the calculated difference as key:

```
0 -> 1 occurrence (index 2)
1 -> 2 negative occurrences (indices 1, 4), 2 positive occurrences (indices 0, 3).
```

The concrete indices are not stored, I have only included them as explanation. And don’t store the 0 entry. Because of the `i < j` restriction we cannot use it for anything. So in your example case we have only:

```
1 -> 2 negative occurrences, 2 positive occurrences
```

Now our goal can be reached by combining each index from entry with key `-n` and with each index from entry `n`. We need to sort each pair such that the other condition, `i < j` is fulfilled. This is always possible since the same index will not be counted as both positive and negative. So the number of pairs from entry `n` of the map is the product of the two counts of negative and positive occurrences. In your case you have only one `n`, in other cases there could be many, so add the numbers of pairs from them all together. In the example we have just 2 * 2 = 4 pairs. This result agrees with your question.

Edit: Complexity consideration: The complexity of my approach depends on the complexity of the map operations, which in turn depend on the map implementation you choose. For most map implementations the construction of the map will be the time consuming part, and it will take O(n * cost of map lookup). Assuming that lookup in a `HashMap` is somewhere between linear and O(log n) you can get something between O(n) and O(n * log n). In any case better than your O(n ^ 2).

### My original idea

My original idea was to generate all the pairs. The idea may be easier to follow, so I let it stand here. It does not perform better than O(n ^ 2), though.

Store the indices into a multimap or map of lists where the calculated differences are keys. In the example you will get

```
-1 -> 1, 4
 0 -> 2
 1 -> 0, 3
```

Now our goal can be reached by combining each index from entry with key `-n` and with each index from entry `n`. Only we need to sort each pair such that the other condition, `i < j` is fulfilled (this is always possible since the same index will not be in both lists).

Unsorted pairs:

```
(1, 0), (1, 3), (4, 0), (4, 3)
```

Sorted pairs (that is, with `i < j`):

```
(0, 1), (1, 3), (0, 4), (3, 4)
```

For comparison, after correcting your own code produces:

```
(0, 1), (0, 4), (1, 3), (3, 4)
```

They are the same 4 pairs, only the order is different. Sorting will solve that if it matters.

Comment: Are you sure this has time complexity < O(n*n)?

Comment: I think you mean `array[i] - i == -(array[j] - j)`?

Comment: You're wrong regarding the complexity. The goal is to "Determine the number of cases", and this can be done without generating them. So you're `O(n)` (assuming a `HashMultimap` without pathological collisions; forget the trees; actually a `MultiSet` would do, as all you need is counting).

Comment: You’re right, @maaartinus. In fact, all we need is a map from a calculated difference to a count. Then multiplying the counts for each `n` and `-n` will give us the result. We’re somewhere around O(n * log n) or better.